# PHP Json Encoding w/ quote escaping in 5.2?

Tags: php, javascript, encoding, json

I'm playing with the flickr api and php.  I want to pass some information from PHP to Javascript through Ajax.  I have the following code:

```
json_encode($pics);
```

which results in the following example JSON string:

```
[{"id":"4363603591","title":"blue, white and red...another seattle view","date_faved":"1266379499"},{"id":"4004908219","title":"\u201cI just told you my dreams and you made me see that I could walk into the sun and I could still be me and now I can't deny nothing lasts forever.\u201d","date_faved":"1259987670"}]
```

Javascript has problems with this, however, due to the unescaped single-quote in the second item ("can't deny").

I want to use the function json_encode with the options parameter to make it strip the quotes, but that's only available in PHP 5.3, and I'm running 5.2 (not my server).  Is there a fast way to run through the entire array and escape everything before encoding it in Json?  I looked for a way to do this, but it all seems to deal with encoding it as the data is generated, something I cannot do as I'm not the one generating the data.

If it helps, I'm currently using the following javascript after the ajax request:

```
var photos = eval('(' + resptxt + ')');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) instead of `eval()`?  Details [here](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Answer (score 1):

str_replace('\'', '\\'', json_encode($pics))

Comment: Hm, but what about the double quotes?  I can't run the same type of replace because it would replace all of the quoted values too!

Comment: This won't work in PHP you can't do '\'', '\\''... because php will give you an error... to many single quotes... you want something like this str_replace("'", "\'", json_encode($invoices));

Comment: @NickAldwin use strtr.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a (recursive) foreach to walk through the array and manipulate them manually. You can do a str_replace, but addslashes works just as fine (and addcslashes is even better.)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of (well, not afraid, but hoping there was a faster way).